# Shouldn't a SVM binary classifier understand the threshold from the training set?

Tags: apache-spark, classification, svm, libsvm

I'm very confused about SVM classifiers and I'm sorry if I'll sound stupid.
I'm using the Spark library for java http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-linear-methods.html, the first example from the Linear Support Vector Machines paragraph. On this training set:

```
1 1:10
1 1:9
1 1:9
1 1:9
0 1:1
1 1:8
1 1:8
0 1:2
0 1:2
0 1:3
```

the prediction on values: 8, 2 and 1 are all positive (1). Given the training set, I would expect them to be positive, negative, negative. It gives negative only on 0 or negative values. I read that the standard threshold is "positive" if the prediction is a positive double, "negative" if it's negative, and I've seen that there is a method to manually set the threshold. But isn't this the exact reason I need a binary classifier for? I mean, if I know in advance what the threshold is I can distinguish between positive and negative values, so why bother training a classifier?

UPDATE:
Using this python code from a different library:

```
X = [[10], [9],[9],[9],[1],[8],[8],[2],[2],[3]]
y = [1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0]
​
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.cross_validation import StratifiedKFold
from sklearn.metrics import precision_recall_fscore_support, accuracy_score
import numpy as np
​
# we convert our list of lists in numpy arrays
X = np.array(X)
y = np.array(y)
# we compute the general accuracy of the system - we need more "false questions" to continue the study
accuracy = []
​
#we do 10 fold cross-validation - to be sure to test all possible combination of training and test
kf_total = StratifiedKFold(y, n_folds=5, shuffle=True)
for train, test in kf_total:
    X_train, X_test = X[train], X[test]
    y_train, y_test = y[train], y[test]
    print X_train
    clf = SVC().fit(X_train, y_train) 
    y_pred = clf.predict(X_test)
    print "the classifier says: ", y_pred
    print "reality is:          ", y_test
    print accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)
    print ""
    accuracy.append(accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred))

print sum(accuracy)/len(accuracy)
```

the results are correct:

```
######
1 [0]
######
2 [0]
######
8 [1]
```

So I think it's possible for a SVM classifier to understand the threshold by itself; how can I do the same with the spark library?

SOLVED: I solved the issue changing the example to this:

```
SVMWithSGD std = new SVMWithSGD();
std.setIntercept(true);
final SVMModel model = std.run(training.rdd());
```

From this:

```
final SVMModel model = SVMWithSGD.train(training.rdd(), numIterations);
```

The standard value for "intercept" is false, which is what I needed to be true.

Comment: Your data is linearly separable, the training set should be classified 100% correct by every SVM implementation. without weight the separation should be exactly at 5.5. The problem must be in your implementation.

Answer (score 0):

If you search for probability calibration you will find some research on a related matter (recalibrating the outputs to return better scores).

If your problem is a binary classification problem, you can calculate the slope of the cost by assigning vales to true/false positive/negative options multiplied by the class ratio. You can then form a line with the given AUC curve that intersects at only one point to find a point that is in some sense optimal as a threshold for your problem.

Threshold is one value that will differentiate classes .